# Backing up MySQL database from java app

Tags: java, mysql

I'm trying to backup my MySQL database from my Java app.
Here's the code:

```
String executeCmd = "mysqldump.exe -u " + dbUser + " -p" + dbPass;
executeCmd += " --all-databases > " + savePath;
System.out.println(executeCmd);
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(executeCmd);
```

But it do nothing. If I copy output of System.out.println and paste it into cmd it works fine. Can someone say what's wrong in Java?

Answer (score 1):

I strongly suggest that you read [this canonical article on JavaWorld about `Runtime.getRuntime()`](https://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html).  The long story short, you have two major problems with your code.  First, you are not waiting for the process to complete, and second you are not handling the output from that process.  Taking the following code partially from the above article, we can write a version which should work:

```
try {            
    Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
    String executeCmd = "mysqldump.exe -u " + dbUser + " -p" + dbPass;
    executeCmd += " --all-databases > " + savePath;
    Process proc = rt.exec(executeCmd);
    InputStream stderr = proc.getErrorStream();
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(stderr);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
    String line = null;
    System.out.println("<ERROR>");
    while ( (line = br.readLine()) != null)
        System.out.println(line);
    System.out.println("</ERROR>");
    int exitVal = proc.waitFor();
    System.out.println("Process exitValue: " + exitVal);
}
catch (Throwable t) {
    t.printStackTrace();
}
```

If, as you say, the call to `mysqldump` is successful from the same machine where you are running this code, then there should be no error warnings.  If there are any errors, then above snippet should put you in a good position to see what they are, and deal with them.

Comment: Here's the output:<ERROR>
mysqldump: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
</ERROR>
Process exitValue: 1
It write's the same in cmd. But works.

If i set space after -p tag. This message disapears. In Java i get exitValue: 1. But in cmd it still works fine.

Comment: Yes. But backup file creates.

Comment: @КонстантинПрудников I researched `mysqldump`, and what I have found is that using a password from the command line isn't really recommended at all.  One way around this is to configure a credential store.  You could try doing this, to make the warning go away, and then perhaps the above code would run.

Comment: if i set " " afer -p tag (String executeCmd = "mysqldump.exe -u " + dbUser + " -p " + dbPass;) this warning go away. it work in cmd without warnings. And your code dont't show warnings. it simply says exitValue: 1

Answer (score 0):

Try to use waitFor(), something like this.

```
public boolean backupDB(String dbName, String dbUserName, String dbPassword, String path) {
        String executeCmd = "mysqldump.exe -u " + dbUserName + " -p "+dbPassword+" --all-databases > " + path;

        Process runtimeProcess;
        try {

            runtimeProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(executeCmd);
            int processComplete = runtimeProcess.waitFor();

            if (processComplete == 0) {
                System.out.println("Backup created successfully");
                return true;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Could not create the backup");
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Are you getting any error? What is the output you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Problem was in executeCmd.
It works this way:

```
String executeCmd = "mysqldump.exe -u " + dbUser + " -p" + dbPass+" dbName -r " + savePath;
```

I don't understand why it don't work with --all-databases, but problem solved. THX for all.